# Two branches pull request yeilds entirely different commit histories

Tags: git, github

I cloned a repo to my computer:

```
git clone <repo>
```

Then I created a new repo on Github.

In my cloned repo I assigned a remote origin:

```
git remote <new repo>
```

I got two branches: `main` (marked as 'default' on Github) and `master`.

I started working with `master`. Everything was fine, I could even 'push' my changes. But when I tried to create a pull request to merge `master` into `main`.

I didn't get a PR button and got the notification that

> There isn’t anything to compare.
>
> main and master are entirely different commit histories.

I tried to find a solution, but because of my lack of experience with Git I can't decide if one of them fits in to my problem. Here are many [examples][1].

How can I merge my changes from `master` into `main`?

Answer (score 3):

If you're receiving this error for a newly created Github repo, it's likely that you added files to your default `main` branch during project creation, for example a `README.md`.

Your local `master` branch will indeed have no shared history with your remote `main` branch, and you cannot create pull requests from one to the other.

To fix this, you need to check fetch your `main` branch locally and then rebase your `master` branch on top of it, so that it shares `main`'s history:

```
git fetch
git checkout master
git rebase origin/main
```

Comment: But I need to make a PR. So how to do it then?

Comment: You can't, until there is something on `main`, and the sane way to put something on `main` is the instructions in my answer. You cannot issue a pull request against `main` in a brand new repo with no commits, that is impossible. If you've already put something on main (for example, by creating a README during repo creation), then you have indeed produced two branches with no shared history, and you need to checkout `main` locally and rebase your `master` onto `main` before creating a pull request.

Comment: If I fork the original repo (that I cloned), create a new branch and copy my files into this new repo will help? So I mean I have to start from scratch a new repo.

Comment: You can do that, but you don't have to.